# How to refactor two loops to use one method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code, and would like the loop to only exist once, but my return statements are different for each:

```
def valid?
  patterns.each do |pattern|
    match_data = text.match(pattern)
    if match_data
      return true
    end
  end
  false
end

def pattern_matched
  patterns.each do |pattern|
    match_data = text.match(pattern)
    if match_data
      return pattern.source
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

I don't want to store anything in state as I want these functions to be pure and independent of each other.

How can I write a helper function that runs the loop but returns either true/false OR pattern/nil?

Comment: These two methods, even though they do very similar things, serve *very* different purposes.  What were you hoping to gain by unifying them?

Comment: Don't write code that returns a variety of types; If you can figure out the logic it'll be more difficult to maintain, plus any code calling it will have to test for any of those possible types and then react accordingly, creating an additional problem area to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
def valid?
  !pattern_matched.nil?
end

def pattern_matched
  patterns.detect { |pattern| text.match(pattern) }&.source
end
```

I also replaced `each` loop as for finding first matching element `detect` seems like a better choice.

Comment: clean solution although I would go with `pattern.source if pattern`